# Refactoring old JS. Migrate from legacy JS to webpack. Do I even need bundler or stay vanila JS?

Tags: javascript, webpack, refactoring, legacy, legacy-code

For example, I have files: /js/common.js and /js/jqextend.js.
Most of legacy JS files have such architechture:

```
;var common = (function() {
    functionName = function () {
        
    }
    
})();
```

So, is it better migrate to webpack or stay like this?

If I'll use webpack, I need somehow use it with the old js, without modules, exports, etc. So, do I need add support import/export for all my JS? It looks like unrealistic for me, because there are about 50-100 JS files and changing all of them might take very long time.

Comment: "I am adding webpack into an old project" why? For what reason? The answer to your question probably depends a lot on why you're doing this in the first place...

Comment: And when you try to answer that, also consider that webpack is not the only fruit, and  you might be far better off with something like esbuild, which is a tool _for_ JS but not written _in_ JS, so it's several orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @Jared Smith, I mean legacy project. It is still supported and now I've started refactoring this.

Comment: @Geckon01 webpack is a bundler. It comes with a plugin architecture that lets it also work as a task runner, but it's still at it's heart a bundler. You have a bunch of global variables/mutations of a global namespace instead of real modules to be bundled. Is it really such a big deal? Hopefully if you were writing a new app from scratch you'd do it differently but it's already working. So what value are you expecting webpack to bring to the table? Because we can't really give you good guidance without an answer to that question. What are the problems you hope a refactor will solve?

Comment: @Jared Smith Understood. Let me describe the goal more precisely. I have web CRM which containts 2 parts: first is web shop that is visible for users, second is admin panel for it. User part is more modern and at least 50% refactored. Huge amount of user part is moved to Vue.js. Admin panel at least moslty legacy. So, what I want achive:
1. Vue components through webpack.
2. Start refactoring all old JS, but not rewrite them all at once. Firstly just unite them with webpack. Then refcator every .js one by one.

Comment: Cool. Yeah you're going to have to refactor to use modules, sorry to bear the bad news